# How can I use parameters (or measures) within a new column in PowerBI?

Tags: parameters, powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, measure

I have created a parameter (`P1`) which I would like to use in the creation of a new column. The new column is equal to `P1 * ColA`, where `ColA` is some other column with numerical values. The value of the new column should change if the user changes the value of `P1`.

So far, I have tried creating the new column like this:

```
NewColumn =

VAR P1_val = 'P1'[P1 Value]
RETURN P1_val * 'Table1'[ColA]
```

This returns blank. I also tried using the SELECTEDVALUE() function, like this, but this still returns blank:

```
NewColumn =

VAR P1_val = SELECTEDVALUE('P1'[P1 Value])
RETURN P1_val * 'Table1'[ColA]
```

If I try the multiplication with a hard-coded value, like this, it works. But the value of the parameter is not being recognized.

```
NewColumn =

VAR P1_val = 3
RETURN P1_val * 'Table1'[ColA]
```